# How optimize code (java)

Tags: java

I have a task. When a user registers on the site, his id can be his favorite number. But if there is already a user with such an id, then the id of this user becomes the smallest free number following his favorite number. But when the tourist leaves the site, his identifier ceases to be occupied, and the next user can occupy his id. For example:

```
Input:
first line value `n` is amount of users
the next `n` lines contain two values: first value can be 1  if user register on site or 2 if user leave site
 second value is favorite number (1<=x<=1000000000)
Input:
7
1 10
1 10
1 10
1 11
1 20
2 11
1 11

Output:
10
11
12
13
20
11
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
 public static final Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
 public static final int SIZE = 2;
 public static final int MAXNUMBER = 1000000000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int t = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        Map<Integer, Integer> favoriteNumbers = new HashMap<>();
        int []a = new int[SIZE];
        while(t-- > 0) {
            for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
                a[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
            if(a[0] == 1 && !favoriteNumbers.containsValue(a[1])) {
                System.out.println(a[1]);
                favoriteNumbers.put(a[1], a[1]);
            }
            else if (a[0] == 1 && favoriteNumbers.containsValue(a[1])) {
                for(int i= (a[1] + 1); i<MAXNUMBER; ) {
                    if(!favoriteNumbers.containsValue(i)) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        favoriteNumbers.put(i, i);
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            } else if(a[0] == 2 && favoriteNumbers.containsValue(a[1])){
                favoriteNumbers.remove(a[1], a[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's work correctly, but I get run time exceeded. The maximum execution time should be 1 second. Please help me how I can optimize code and speed up runtime.

Comment: Never need to use a map to store identical Object as key and value, use a List

Answer (score 5):

`favoriteNumbers.containsValue(a[1])` takes linear time (since finding a value in a `HashMap` requires iterating over all the values). `favoriteNumbers.containsKey(a[1])` would take constant time.

Of course, since the key and value of your map are identical, you should use `HashSet` instead of `HashMap`, and once you change `favoriteNumbers` to a `HashSet`, `favoriteNumbers.contains(a[1])` would take constant time.

Here's an optimized version using `HashSet`.
Edit:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static final Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    public static final int SIZE = 2;
    public static final int MAXNUMBER = 1000000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int t = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        Set<Integer> favoriteNumbers = new HashSet<>();
        int []a = new int[SIZE];
        while(t-- > 0) {
            for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
                a[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
            if(a[0] == 1) {
                for(int i = a[1]; i < MAXNUMBER; i++) {
                    if (favoriteNumbers.add(i)) {
                        sb.append(i + "\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if(a[0] == 2) {
                favoriteNumbers.remove(a[1]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the program work faster, but i still get run time exceeded

Comment: @anna How many inputs are you supposed to process in less than 1 second?

Comment: may be there is another an optimized algorithm to solve this task?

Comment: can be 1<=n<=100 000

Comment: @anna there aren't any substantial optimizations to make (i.e. optimizations that would improve the asymptotic running time), but there are some minor improvements to make - for example, you can call `remove` without calling `contains` first.

Comment: thank you for your help, but I again get run time exceeded

Comment: @anna OK, here's another suggestion - instead of multiple println statements, you can append the outputs to a StringBuilder and have one `System.out.println(sb.toString());` in the end to print the full output.

Comment: @anna yes, something like this

Comment: still run time exceeded(